# Withdrawal "invalid scope"

Tags: php, permissions, cryptography, coinbase-api

I'm trying to use API **withdrawal/crypto** using sandbox of **Pro Coinbase** but i get:

```
Code: 403
Message: Invalid scope
```

I have this config in API permission settings

[image]

So, what's the wrong? Maybe it's a problem of sandbox? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 403, "Invalid scope" error also occurs in the coinbase sandbox when one uses the [sandbox ui](https://public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com/portfolios/withdrawals).

Here's a screenshot of it happening when using a sandbox generated destination address.
[image: the ui]

Based on this, this appears to be an issue with the Coinbase Pro Sandbox itself.

Answer (score 1):

scope restrictions:
**wallet:transactions:send** is limited $1.00/day per user in coinbase.
Your withdrawal limit is : $1.00/day ( 1 usd = 0.000028 BTC, at this moment)